# matlab set center of output figure to [0 0 0]

Tags: matlab, visualization, matrix

I have a few set of data of three dimensional matrices, n x 3 with x, y and z coordinates.
I viewed the matrices in the figure window.

```
% read function;
OBJ1=read_obj('subject1.obj');
FV.vertices=OBJ1.vertices;
FV.faces=OBJ1.objects(2).data.vertices;
figure, patch(FV,'facecolor',[0 0 1]); camlight
grid on
axis equal
```

I want to read other sets of data by using the same function, but sets the **center of each figure** (not the center of origin) at [x y z]=[0 0 0].

Note that when I use the function above, the center of outputs is not always at [0 0 0].

Is it can be done by using translation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a perfectly square set of axes with the center at $(0,0,0)$, while keeping all of the data on screen, I'd do something like this:

```
axis auto;
a = axis;
amax = max(abs(a));
axis([-amax,amax,-amax,amax,-amax,amax]);
```

If you like your axes limits to be integral, change `max(abs(a))` to `ceil(max(abs(a)))`.

Comment: what if the center of 3D figure is not originally at [0 0 0]? for example: [x y z]=[29.24 -11.83 103]. can i really translate it to be [0 0 0]?

Comment: Well, you've gotta do what looks right. But the purpose of `axis auto` is to get the extends of the 3-D figure. I use those to determine the smallest cube, centered at the origin, that contains the extents of the figure.